# which number has div with specific class

Tags: jquery

I would like to have number (int) of ul with class 'currentWeek'. My html look like this:

```
<div class="calendarContainer">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="currentWeek">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this is how I could all UL's

```
var weeksCount = widget.find(".calendarContainer").children().length;
```

But I have no idea how to know that currentWeek is third

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
widget.find('.currentWeek').index()
```

Quoting the [**.index**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) doc:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

You might want to add 1 to result, if you need to get the natural (not 0-based) number of that element.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [**index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method to get the index of element within siblings. It is zero-idexed, means you will get 0 for first element and 1 for second and so on.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zCVmT/)**

```
$('.currentWeek').index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$(".currentWeek").index();
```

If you need to specify the element relatively to which you need to count use:

```
$(".currentWeek").index(".calendarContainer ul");
```

Both approaches return **2**, since indices start with zero.